# AngularFire2 : Access the FirebaseDatabase Conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In my project I am having a situation in which I want to access the path in my AngularFire2 db.list. But there is a catch, I get the userId on the form submit like `ieRq3uAs2jdge4YAw8eQP4Ctg2`.

```
todoapp-9652a
|- todos
   |-KkasXPx6_g0f6ZnryF2
   |-Kkatv9-gcKvzsexT1iH
   |-Kkau3wIOOHlQqo_Uit3
   |-KkayfMh9-3Hqb_dnXDg
   |- POMJuxiLD6MGPZPI9UDLtQGcktv2
      |-data1
      |-data2
   |- ieRq3uAs2jdge4YAw8eQCRGtg2
```

Now if I get the `db.list("todos/"+userID)` in the `submit()` function it tries to get the db.list on load and says `userID` is undefined.

So my query is How can I get the db.list at the run time in order to push the data in my correct user's profile.

CODE :

```
onSubmit(db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
        console.log("New Task",this.newTask);

        this.todosEdit.subscribe(snapshots=> {
            snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                if(snapshot.val().id){
                    this.todoListHighestId = snapshot.val().id;
                    //console.log("this.todoListHighestId",this.todoListHighestId, snapshot.val().id)
                }
                else {
                    this.todoListHighestId = 10;
                }
            });
        });
        this.finalObject = {
            'id' : this.todoListHighestId+1,
            'title' : this.newTask.title,
            'description' :this.newTask.description,
            'status':true,
            'completed' :false,
            'userID':this.newTask.userID
        };
        this.todosEdit.subscribe(todosData=>{
            console.log("todosData ",todosData);
        })
        //push(this.finalObject);

        console.log("final OBject",this.finalObject);
        this.newTask = new todo();
        /* To reset the form*/
            this.active=false;
            setTimeout ( ()=> this.active=true,0);
        /* To reset the form*/
    }
```

Comment: `db.list("/todos"+userID)` is missing a `/` between `todos` and the UID. Use `db.list("/todos/"+userID)` instead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for pointing that out. but that was a typing mistake. issue is still the same as it was.

Comment: The code snippet you shared contains no calls to `db.list("todos/"+userID)`. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be hard to say what's going wrong in that call.